# Setting environment variable for JSON files in AWS Lambda Chalice

Tags: aws-lambda, google-bigquery, environment-variables, chalice

I'm working with some [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/) project. Using Python library for [BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/) on my laptop, I can successfully download the dataset after passing the [authentication credential](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#setting_up_authentication) by environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`. As the documentation explains, this environment variable points to the location of a JSON file containing the credential.

Now I want to run this code on [Amazon Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) using [Chalice](https://github.com/aws/chalice). I know there's an [option for environment variable](https://chalice.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/configfile.html#environment-variables) in Chalice, but I don't know how to include a JSON file inside of a Chalice app and pass its location as an environment variable. Moreover, I'm not sure whether it's safe to pass the credential as a JSON file in Chalice.

Does anyone have some experience on how to pass Google Credential as an environment variable for Chalice app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just embed the contents of the JSON file as an environment variable in Chalice, and then use the GCP `Client.from_service_account_info()` method to load credentials from memory instead of a file. This would not be advised since your private GCP credentials would then likely be committed to source control.

Might I suggest that you entertain other approaches to passing your GCP credentials other than environment variables. You could store this JSON object in [AWS System Manager Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-paramstore.html) as a secure parameter. Your AWS Lambda function could then use the boto3 [`ssm.get_parameter()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ssm.html#SSM.Client.get_parameter) method when needed.

You could also consider [AWS Secrets Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/secrets-manager/) as another similar alternative.